# pip install and custom index url

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I am getting the following exception while trying to install using `pip`:

`Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', error(111, 'Connection refused'))': /simple/<package>/`

Where does `pip` install the packages from?

How do I proxy or use alternate internal site to get these packages?

Answer (score 8):

`pip install` looks at `http://pypi.python.org/simple/<package>/`

You might see the following error in case the connection to pypi.python.org is not open to access (e.g. because of your firewall rules).

`Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', error(111, 'Connection refused'))': /simple/<package>/`

The `-v` option (enabling debug logging/verbose mode is a nice way to start debugging).

Often companies create a proxy to http://pypi.python.org/simple so all the internal sites can access it when they are not exposed to internet.

We can configure this url in `pip.conf`. By default `pip` looks into `$HOME/.pip/pip.conf` for configuration data.

```
[global]
extra-index-url = https://my-pypi.mywebsite.com/simple
timeout = 10
```

If you have set the conf and yet if the pip conf is not being picked check that `pip.conf` is in the right home directory for the user.

e.g.
/root, / or /home/user

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

1. `unset all_proxy` (optional in case none are set)
2. `pip install 'requests[socks]'` **inside** the venv